# how do i use an assembly containing a user control in visual studio 2005

Tags: asp.net

Please can you tell me how I would use a user control that is available to be as a dll in visual studio 2005 with .net 2.0. I have seen this article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx#customcontrolfromusercontrol_topic7

but I am none the wiser as I didn't compile the dll myself so I don't know how to add the dll to the web.config file or what its strong name is (step 5). Furthermore i dont know how to register a directive for the dll to the page either.

I tried to add the dll to the toolbar but I got the error that there are no components available in the dll.

Thanks a lot for any help you can give

Comment: just a head up, this is gnarly.  I've just set up some post build copy routines to share user controls across my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Is there no documentation of the control? You will at least need the namespace and the class name of the control you want to use.

Using a third party control is usually done in 3 steps:

1. Add the assembly (DLL) file to your references. (Right click on the folder in the solution explorer and select "Add reference...". Then select your DLL file)
2. Register your control at the top of your .ascx or .aspx file like this (This is an example. TagPrefix you can choose yourself. Namespace and Assebmly you need to know.):

   ```
   <%@ Register TagPrefix="rjs" Namespace="RJS.Web.WebControl" Assembly="RJS.Web.WebControl.PopCalendar.Net.2008" %>
   ```
3. Create the controls on your page (Using your TagPrefix from above and the name of the control.):

   ```
   <rjs:PopCalendar CssClass="Small" id="dateFrom" runat="server" Buttons="[<][m][y]  [>]" BorderWidth="1px" Separator="." RequiredDate="False"></rjs:PopCalendar>
   ```

Additionally you may need additional settings in your web.config file.